# Simultaneously accessing textbox and select using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create a directive where when the user type '@u' displaying users or '@c'displaying countries in the text area , I want to display the select options below the text-area based on the keyword and given access to move up and down to select the option.At the same time user can also need able to type the text in text area.Can anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Working plunkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/CCEqiupjdHyaF2MriJil?p=preview

```
    angular.module('testApp',[]).controller('testCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.users = ['user1','user2','user3'];
  $scope.country = ['IND','AUS','ENG'];
}]).directive('userCountry',function(){
    return{
      scope:{
        users : '=users',
        country:'=country'
      },
      restrict : 'EA',
      templateUrl:'userCountry.html',
      controller: ['$scope',function($scope){
        $scope.watchStart=false
        $scope.textareaChange = function(evt) {
          if(evt.key === "@"){
            $scope.watchStart = true;
            return;
          }
          if($scope.watchStart){
            if(evt.key === "u"){
              $scope.options=$scope.users;
            }else if(evt.key === "c"){
              $scope.options=$scope.country;
            }else{
              $scope.options=[];
            }
            $scope.watchStart = false;
          }
        }
      }]
    };
});
```

Please go through the plunkr. I have excluded following :

- Opening of select programmatically
- On select field value selection change in textarea (I assume you want to achieve this) - This can be done by harnessing their individual models

Comment: Thanks for you response.My requirement is without using the mouse I need to choose the option and continue typing in the text area.Based on the typings using @ the suggestion should display and without using mouse the option can be either choose or continue with the typing.